# Chaining gradle tasks and gradle lifecycle

Tags: gradle

I have a basic interrogation about the Gradle lifecycle. My project is a multi-module project.

I noticed that the following command:

```
./gradlew clean bignibou-server:run
```

Is not equivalent to running the following two commands run in that order:

```
./gradlew clean

./gradlew bignibou-server:run
```

`bignibou-server` is one of my modules.

The output from the first command results in a different output from the two commands below.

Can someone please explain why that is possibly pointing to relevant documentation?

**edit**: In the first case one of the generated sources output gets deleted whereas it is not deleted in the second case. How can this be?

**edit 2**:

from root `build.gradle`:

```
import io.franzbecker.gradle.lombok.task.DelombokTask

def javaVersion = 1.8

buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/release" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/" }
    }

    ext {
        javaLanguageLevel = '1.8'
    }

    ext['mockito.version'] = "${mockitoVersion}"
    ext['hibernate.version'] = "${hibernateVersion}"

    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath("io.franzbecker:gradle-lombok:${gradleLombokVersion}")
    }
}

configure(allprojects) { project ->
    group = "com.bignibou"

    apply plugin: 'java'
    apply plugin: 'eclipse'
    apply plugin: 'idea'

    configurations {
        mapstruct
    }

    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/release" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
        maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
        maven { url "https://artifacts.elastic.co/maven" }
    }

    compileJava {
        sourceCompatibility = javaVersion
        targetCompatibility = javaVersion
    }

    test {
        reports.html.destination = file("$reports.html.destination/unit")
        reports.junitXml.destination = file("$reports.junitXml.destination/unit")
    }

    task delombok(type: DelombokTask) {
        ext.outputDir = file("$buildDir/src-delomboked/java")
        outputs.dir(outputDir)
        sourceSets.main.java.srcDirs.each {
            inputs.dir(it)
            args(it, "-d", outputDir)
        }
    }

    // FIXME: refactor paths to generated sources
    task mapStructClean {
        delete file("build/generated-sources/mapstruct/main")
    }

    task generateMainMapperClasses(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build') {
        ext.aptDumpDir = file("${buildDir}/tmp/apt/mapstruct")
        destinationDir = aptDumpDir

        classpath = compileJava.classpath + configurations.mapstruct
        source = file("$buildDir/src-delomboked/java")
        ext.sourceDestDir = file("build/generated-sources/mapstruct/main")

        options.define(
                compilerArgs: [
                        "-nowarn",
                        "-proc:only",
                        "-encoding", "UTF-8",
                        "-processor", "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor" + ',lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor',
                        "-s", sourceDestDir.absolutePath,
                        "-source", rootProject.javaLanguageLevel,
                        "-target", rootProject.javaLanguageLevel,
                ]
        );

        inputs.dir source
        outputs.dir "${buildDir}/generated-sources/mapstruct/main"
        doFirst {
            sourceDestDir.mkdirs()
        }
        doLast {
            aptDumpDir.delete()
        }
    }
}

task wrapper(type: Wrapper) { gradleVersion = '3.5' }
```

from `bignibou-commmon` module:

```
description = "Bignibou Common"

apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok'

configurations {
    querydslapt
    mapstruct
}


dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        dependency "org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:${elasticsearchVersion}"
    }
}

dependencies {

    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-mail")
    compile('org.springframework.security:spring-security-core')
    compile('org.hibernate:hibernate-validator')
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-java8")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jsr310")

    //Spring cloud
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-spring-service-connector")
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-localconfig-connector")
    compile("org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-cloudfoundry-connector")

    // Relational Database
    compile("org.postgresql:postgresql:${postgresqlVersion}")
    compile("org.flywaydb:flyway-core")

    // Connection pooling
    compile("com.zaxxer:HikariCP")

    //Shield
    compile("org.elasticsearch.client:x-pack-transport:${elasticsearchVersion}")
    compile("org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:${elasticsearchVersion}")
    compile("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api")
    compile("org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core")

    // QueryDSL
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-core:${queryDslVersion}")
    compile("com.querydsl:querydsl-jpa:${queryDslVersion}")
    querydslapt("com.querydsl:querydsl-apt:${queryDslVersion}")

    // Jackson
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core")
    compile("com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations")

    compile("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-jdk8:${mapstructVersion}")
    mapstruct("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}")
    compile("org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:${httpClientVersion}")

    compile("org.jasypt:jasypt:${jasyptVersion}")

}

sourceSets {

    main {
        ext.originalJavaSrcDirs = java.srcDirs
        java.srcDir "build/generated-sources/mapstruct/main"
        output.dir("build/generated-mail-templates")
    }

    generated {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["build/generated-sources/java", "build/src-delomboked/java", "build/generated-sources/mapstruct/main"]
        }
    }
}

bootRepackage {
    enabled = false
}

task generateQueryDSL(type: JavaCompile, group: 'build') {
    description "Generates the QueryDSL query types"
    source = sourceSets.main.java
    classpath = configurations.compile + configurations.querydslapt
    options.compilerArgs = [
            "-proc:only",
            "-processor",
            "com.querydsl.apt.jpa.JPAAnnotationProcessor" + ',lombok.launch.AnnotationProcessorHider$AnnotationProcessor'
    ]
    destinationDir = sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs.iterator().next()
}

// FIXME: add cssFile &
// FIXME: add dependsOn processMailTemplates &
// FIXME: clean mail templates html
// FIXME: ensure build is stopped if templates are not processed

task npmInstall(type: Exec) {
    description "npm install"
    commandLine 'npm', 'install'
}

task processMailTemplates {
    description "Processes mail templates"
    dependsOn npmInstall

    def templateSrcDir = "src/main/templates/mail/"
    def templateDestDir = "build/generated-mail-templates/META-INF/templates/mail/"

    mkdir templateDestDir

    def templateNames = []

    fileTree(dir: templateSrcDir, include: '**/*.html').visit {
        FileVisitDetails details -> templateNames << details.file.name
    }

    templateNames.each { templateName -> inlineCss(templateSrcDir + templateName, templateDestDir + templateName) }

    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}

static def inlineCss(src, dest) {
    def juice = 'node_modules/.bin/juice'
    def juiceResourcesDir = 'src/main/templates/misc/'
    def juiceArgs = "--options-file ${juiceResourcesDir}juiceOptions.json --css ${juiceResourcesDir}mailStyle.css"
    "${juice} ${juiceArgs} ${src} ${dest}".execute(null, new File('bignibou-common'))
}


compileJava {
    dependsOn generateQueryDSL
    source generateQueryDSL.destinationDir
}

compileGeneratedJava {
    dependsOn generateQueryDSL
    options.warnings = false
    classpath += sourceSets.main.runtimeClasspath
}

idea {
    module {
        sourceDirs += file('build/generated-sources/java')
    }
}

processResources.dependsOn processMailTemplates
compileJava.dependsOn generateMainMapperClasses
generateMainMapperClasses.dependsOn mapStructClean
generateMainMapperClasses.dependsOn delombok


clean {
    delete sourceSets.generated.java.srcDirs
}
```

from `bignibou-server` module:

```
description = "Bignibou Server"

configurations {
    mapstruct
    integrationTest
    integrationTestCompile.extendsFrom testCompile
    integrationTestRuntime.extendsFrom testRuntime
}

apply plugin: 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'application'


dependencyManagement {
    dependencies {
        dependency "org.elasticsearch:elasticsearch:${elasticsearchVersion}"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile project(":bignibou-common")
    compile project(":bignibou-client")

    //Spring boot
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa") {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.tomcat', module: 'tomcat-jdbc'
    }
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-redis") {
        exclude group: 'redis.clients', module: 'jedis'
    }
    compile("biz.paluch.redis:lettuce:${lettuceVersion}")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-cache")

    // Miscellaneous
    compile("commons-collections:commons-collections")
    compile("org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:${commonLangVersion}")
    mapstruct("org.mapstruct:mapstruct-processor:${mapstructVersion}")

    //Caching
    compile("org.hibernate:hibernate-ehcache")
    compile("com.github.ben-manes.caffeine:caffeine:${caffeineVersion}")

    // Spring Session
    compile("org.springframework.session:spring-session")

    // Testing
    testCompile project(":bignibou-test")
}

run {
    systemProperty "spring.cloud.propertiesFile", System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/spring-cloud.properties"
}

springBoot {
    mainClassName = "com.bignibou.Application"
}

sourceSets {

    main {
        ext.originalJavaSrcDirs = java.srcDirs
        java.srcDir "build/generated-sources/mapstruct/main"
    }

    generated {
        java {
            srcDirs = ["build/src-delomboked/java", "build/generated-sources/mapstruct/main"]
        }
    }

    integrationTest {
        java.srcDirs = ['src/it/java']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src/it/resources', 'src/main/resources']
        compileClasspath = sourceSets.main.output + configurations.testRuntime
        runtimeClasspath = output + compileClasspath
    }
}

task integrationTest(type: Test) {
    description "Run the integration tests."
    testClassesDir = sourceSets.integrationTest.output.classesDir
    classpath = sourceSets.integrationTest.runtimeClasspath
    reports.html.destination = file("$reports.html.destination/integration")
    reports.junitXml.destination = file("$reports.junitXml.destination/integration")
}

compileJava.dependsOn generateMainMapperClasses
generateMainMapperClasses.dependsOn mapStructClean
generateMainMapperClasses.dependsOn delombok

check.dependsOn integrationTest
integrationTest.shouldRunAfter test
```

**edit 3**: The folder that gets deleted in by the first command and not the second is the following (from `bignibou-common` module):

```
build/generated-mail-templates
```

**edit 4**: I noticed that after commenting out the `output.dir(...` call (see below), the `build/generated-mail-templates` is not deleted but unfortunately the templates are not included in the classpath...

```
   sourceSets {
      main {
        ext.originalJavaSrcDirs = java.srcDirs
        java.srcDir "build/generated-sources/mapstruct/main"
        //output.dir("build/generated-mail-templates")
      }
```

Comment: Might be easier to explain if you posted the code of the build, and the output you get in the two cases.

Comment: @JBNizet I have edited my post with a first edit. I will include parts of the build script in a second edit.

Comment: @JBNizet I have edited my post accordingly.

Comment: You can see my build script is quite big. That is why I was reluctant to include it in the first place.

Comment: Not sure exactly how it explains what you're seeing, but you're doing the template generation during the configuration phase instead of doing it in the execution phase. That means that, whatever the task you ask gradle to execute, the templates are being generated. All the lines except the tw first ones and the last one should be inside a `doLast { }` closure.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Can you please add an answer including the lines of code you are referring to? I am not sure what lines you are referring to... Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
task processMailTemplates {
    description "Processes mail templates"
    dependsOn npmInstall

    def templateSrcDir = "src/main/templates/mail/"
    def templateDestDir = "build/generated-mail-templates/META-INF/templates/mail/"

    mkdir templateDestDir

    def templateNames = []

    fileTree(dir: templateSrcDir, include: '**/*.html').visit {
        FileVisitDetails details -> templateNames << details.file.name
    }

    templateNames.each { templateName -> inlineCss(templateSrcDir + templateName, templateDestDir + templateName) }

    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }
}
```

All this code is executed during the configuration phase, whatever the task you ask gradle to execute. It should instead be executed during the execution phase:

```
task processMailTemplates {
    description "Processes mail templates"
    dependsOn npmInstall

    outputs.upToDateWhen { false }

    doLast {
        def templateSrcDir = "src/main/templates/mail/"
        def templateDestDir = "build/generated-mail-templates/META-INF/templates/mail/"

        mkdir templateDestDir

        def templateNames = []

        fileTree(dir: templateSrcDir, include: '**/*.html').visit {
            FileVisitDetails details -> templateNames << details.file.name
        }

        templateNames.each { templateName -> inlineCss(templateSrcDir + templateName, templateDestDir + templateName) }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of the difference between configuration and execution phase. I have changed my task definition as advised but the discrepancy of behaviors described above remains. Do you have any other idea why that it? Why would

Comment: Not really. I notice you're doing the same mistake in mapStructClean, but I don't think it's the reason for your problem.